# Functions to operate matrix in r

Tags: r, matrix

I have `m <- a 100*6 matrix`. I want to return an `6*6 matrix`, and the entry(i,j)of the `6*6 matrix` contain the following value:

```
(mean(col.i)-mean(col.j))/sd(col.i and col.j)
```

where sd(col.i and col.j) is the standard deviation of all values from both `col.i and col.j`

I want to use apply function to do this, but I don't know how to combine each two columns of matrix m. So how can I get the 6*6 matrix? what function should I use?(in r)

Comment: You might actually be better off with a loop, if only for readability and ease of debugging. Then you can always wrap it in an apply function later if you need performance.

Comment: Can I only use apply function to do this?

Comment: That's the exact opposite of what I suggested. Try it with a *loop* first, just to get the algorithm right. Starting with `apply` is often a form of premature optimization, which is a bad idea in general. However, in this case the answer by @nicola is correct, readable, represents good R style, and is a good demonstration of `mapply` which can be intimidating to learn how to use.

Answer (score 2):

You can create all the combos of the `i,j` indices through `expand.grid` and then use `mapply` to obtain any element of your matrix. Something like this:

```
    #generate a sample matrix
    m<-matrix(runif(600),ncol=6)
    #generate the indices
    indices<-expand.grid(1:6,1:6)
    #the result
    res<-matrix(mapply(function (x,y) (mean(m[,x])-mean(m[,y]))/sd(m[,c(x,y)]),indices[[1]],indices[[2]]),ncol=6)
```

Comment: Note that one of the keys here is that `sd` handles `m[,c(x,y)]` like a vector by stacking the columns, or "unrolling" the matrix (whatever analogy works best).

Answer (score -1):

Without any details on the platform/language you are using, I can give the following general suggestions:
1. Find the means of the elements in each column.
2. Find the sum of squares of the elements in each column.
You can then use the formula given at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Identities_and_mathematical_properties to get the standard deviations that you need. The formula is:

standard deviation = sqrt(1/N * (sum of squares) - (square of the mean))

Comment: I want to use apply function to do this, and that function should be able to work for all matrix.

Comment: He is using R, this information is in the tags of the question